# My dashlets have stopped working after my host moved my domain to another server

Tags: dashboard, hosting

My host moved my site to another server and Drupal/CiviCRM are mainly working fine. However, the dashlets on the dashboard are no longer working. Each dashlet comes up as follows:

> Not Found The requested URL /civicrm/report/instance/42 was not found
>   on this server. Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) Server at
>   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX Port 80

I've tried clearing the caches, upgrading Civi to 4.6.10 and restarting the VPS, but it's not fixed it.

If I look in the Apache error log, it comes up with a version of this error for each dashlet:

> File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs/civicrm/report/instance/42

Does anyone have any idea what might have changed?

Answer (score 5):

Please check your civicrm.settings.php and after that

- Administer - System Settings - Directories
- Administer - System Settings - Resource URLs
- Administer - System Settings - Cleanup Caches and Update Paths

And then Clear Cache again

Comment: Thanks Catorghans. I've tried these steps, but still no joy. I've updated my civicrm.settings.php to the latest template too.

Comment: The weird thing is this:
"File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs/civicrm/report/instance/42" is a combination of filesystem ("/etc/apache2/htdocs") and url ("civicrm/report/instance/42"). 
So it still looks like a setting problem to me.
You can also delete the file cache by removing the content in:
"sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c"
and
remove the file
"sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/Config.IDS.ini"

Answer (score 3):

Ok, my host support team have now fixed the problem. Here's what they did:

> In /etc/hosts, your website XXXXXXXXXXXXX.co.uk was pointing to one
>   server IP address, but the Civi website was running on the other IP
>   address.  I corrected that and things are working now.
>
> Civi seems to be a little unusual in that it fetches sub-pages via php
>   code running server side; this code was not able to access pages on
>   it's own site.

Answer (score 0):

Another case is when you use Geoip blocking on a server that is not located in one of the allowed IP addresses. For instance when you only allow access from France and the server is located in Germany. In that case you have to specifically allow access from the IP address of the webserver. In my case I used an Apache module and had to add the line "allow from server.ip.address". Without that you lock out the server from accessing itself.